# Why animation not working on angularjs bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Why alert div is not fading out. It's disappearing immediately without any animation

```
<div ng-show="error!=null && error.key!='undefined' && error.key==0" 
     ng-animate="'fade'" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <strong>{{error.value}}</strong>
</div>

$timeout(function () {
                        $scope.error = null;
                    }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't make comments with this account but just an FWI, use !== instead of != and === instead of ==

Comment: what's the reason, i am not aware about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons